# Bootstrap 3, colum which should be on the next row as first is alone on next row aligned right in Chrome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Bootstrap and I hope I have made some silly mistake, but I am having a problem with columns in Chrome. It works fine in Firefox and IE.

This is my column class:

```
col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6
```

So I should have 6cols on large display, 3 on med, 2 on small...

This is the layout:

```
@{string classLabel = "col-lg-3"; string classData = "col-lg-9"; string classCol =     "col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6"; }
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="@classCol">
    <div class="@classLabel">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.CountryOriginCode)</div>
    <div class="@classData"> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryOriginCode, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CountriesList)</div>
  </div>

... more columns
here are the wrong displaying columns - first OK, second wrong

  <div class="@classCol">
    <div class="@classLabel">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.RES_RolePrimaryID)</div>
    <div class="@classData">
        <select name="RES_RolePrimaryID" id="RES_RolePrimaryID">
            @foreach (var item in RES_Roles.GetRolesList())
            {
                <option value="@item.RoleID">@item.Name</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="@classCol">
    <div class="@classLabel">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.RES_RoleSecondaryID)</div>
    <div class="@classData">
        <select name="RES_RoleSecondaryID" id="RES_RoleSecondaryID">
            @foreach (var item in RES_Roles.GetRolesList())
            {
                <option value="@item.RoleID">@item.Name</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

What I'm encountering is that after second row (there are 2 selects) the 2nd select should start new row and then other elements should be after it.
BUT it is shown as a last column of the next row and as the only column on that row.

I tried to determine whats wrong by checking CSS in Chrome, going through the code many times but, still can't manage to put it on the beginning of the row

anyone has any suggestions?

here is the image:

[image]